# GCP, the stdout is empty when read cloud function logs by nodejs

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Here is my nodejs code:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

describe('cloud function test suites', () => {
  describe('deleteCampaign test suites', () => {
    const cloudFunctionName = 'deleteCampaign';
    it('should print campaign data', () => {
      const campaign = { id: '1' };
      const encodedCampaign = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(campaign)).toString(
        'base64',
      );
      const data = JSON.stringify({ data: encodedCampaign });

      const executeResultOutput = cp
        .execSync(
          `gcloud beta functions call ${cloudFunctionName} --data '${data}'`,
        )
        .toString();

      const executionId = executeResultOutput.split(': ')[1];

      const logs = cp
        .execSync(
          `gcloud beta functions logs read ${cloudFunctionName} --execution-id ${executionId}`,
        )
        .toString();

      console.log(logs);

      expect(logs).toContain('campaign:  {"id":"1"}');
    });
  });
});
```

I want to print the logs to stdout, but logs is empty string.

But when I read logs using `gcloud` command line, it's ok. The stdout is correct:

```
gcloud beta functions logs read deleteCampaign --execution-id ee5owvtzlekc
LEVEL  NAME            EXECUTION_ID  TIME_UTC                 LOG
D      deleteCampaign  ee5owvtzlekc  2018-09-13 12:46:17.734  Function execution started
I      deleteCampaign  ee5owvtzlekc  2018-09-13 12:46:17.738  campaign:  {"id":"1"}
D      deleteCampaign  ee5owvtzlekc  2018-09-13 12:46:17.742  Function execution took 9 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

I use `jest` and `nodejs` write some tests for my cloud functions. Why the logs is empty string?

Answer (score 0):

The string you are trying to get is empty, because the logs take a bit more time to generate. Even though the Google Cloud Function has finished executing, you'll have to wait a few seconds for the logs to be ready.

Reading your code, you are not letting this happen, hence you are getting an empty string.

The first thing that I noticed reading your code was this part:

```
const executionId = executeResultOutput.split(': ')[1];
```

I understand that you want to extract the Google Cloud Function's Execution ID. I had problems here because the string was not limited to the execution ID, it also included a new line character and the word "result". I made sure to just extract the necessary Execution ID with the next code:

```
const executionId = executeResultOutput.split(':')[1]; //We get the GCP ID. 
const executionId2 = executionId.split("\n")[0].toString(); //removing the right part of the string.
```

If you have found the way to get the execution ID without problems then ignore my code.

Below you can find the code that has worked for me implementing functions.

```
let cloudFunctionLog ='';

function getLogs(){
    console.log('Trying to get logs...');
    const logs = cp
    .execSync(`gcloud beta functions logs read ${cloudFunctionName} --execution-id ${executionId2}`);
    return logs;
}

do{
    cloudFunctionLog=getLogs();
    if(!cloudFunctionLog){
        console.log('Logs are not ready yet...');
    }else{
        console.log(`${cloudFunctionLog}`);
    }
}while(!cloudFunctionLog);//Do it while the string comes empty.
```

When the logs are no longer empty, they'll show up in your console.